# Find the probability of the following Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

A Markov chain with 3 states: $S = \left \{1,2,3\right\}$ has the following transition matrix:

$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0.65 & 0.28 & 0.07\\ 
0.15 & 0.67 & 0.18\\ 
0.12 & 0.36 & 0.52
\end{pmatrix}$

Knowing that the initial state is $2$, what is the probability that after 3 transitions, we will be in state $3$ without going to state $1$ in these 3 steps?

In other words, I need to find the following probability: $P(X_3=3,X_2\neq1,X_1\neq1|X_0 = 2) = \frac{P(X_0=2,X_1\neq1,X_2\neq1,X_3=1)}{P(X_0=2)}$.

I don't know if I have to take cases, like when $X_1=2$ or $X_1=3$ and the same for $X_2$ or there is a quicker way to do it.

Comment: Did you mean $P(X_3=3,X_2\neq1,X_1\neq1|X_0 = 2)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited.

Comment: You need to calculate $P^3$ and then calculate conditional probabilities by  summing over the elements of $P^3$.

Comment: Does that include the fact that we can't go through node 1 in any step?

Answer (score 1):

Let the matrix $P'$ be similar matrix as $P$ but this time the state 1 is terminal. (i.e. the first row is 1 0 0)

Your sollution is the number in the third column and the second row in the matrix $P'^3$.

A short explanation: If you don't want to go via the state 1, you can change the Markow chain in such way that no path leads via state 1. Setting the node 1 to a terminal works perfectly. After that, it is a straightforward calculation.

Comment: Can I know the explanation?

Comment: Sure. Is this explanation sufficient?

Comment: Setting the node 1 to a terminal does not stop us from getting to node 1, if I am not wrong. So if we are at node 2, we can still get to node 1, but we can't leave it.

Comment: We can't leave node 1 and therefore we can't go to node 3 via node 1.